# pass class name via context and use it to store static value in different class

Tags: java, class, methods, static, closures

The dialogue and the array displays just fine, I just want to be able to set the static variable from the originating class within the `onClick` that is in a method that is in a different class. All of the `try`, `catch` and 
`<?>` were things that I put in at the insistence of the compiler:

```
public class Setter
    {
    public void myList(Context context, Class<?> thisclass, int arrayid, String choice)
        {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setItems(arrayid, new OnClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                setChoice(thisclass, context, arrayid, which, choice);
                }
            })
        .create();
        }           
    public void setChoice(Class<?> thisclass, Context context, int arrayid, int which, String choice)
        {
        String[] array = context.getResources().getStringArray(arrayid);
        try
            {
            Field f = thisclass.getDeclaredField(choice);
            f.set(null, array[which]);
            }
        catch (SecurityException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

public class ClassA extends Activity
    {
    static String stringa;
    Setter setted = new Setter();
    ...
    public void onCreate()
        {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        AlertDialog thinga = setted.myList(this, getclass(), R.array.thinga, stringa).show();
        ...
        }
    }
```

When I select an item from the list, I get this from debugger:

```
ClassCache.findFieldByName(Field[], String) line: 438   
Class.getDeclaredField(String) line: 666    
Setter.setChoice(Class, Context, int, int, String) line: 45 // the line with the Field
```

I think I'm passing it the class wrong but this is a bit out of my current depth.

I have a number of different classes each with their own `static String`s. I am passing the method below the name of the `String` (in `choice`) and the `context` of what I had hoped was the original class that called a method that called a method that led to the code below. I was hoping I could call `context.choice = something` and the machine would read that as `ClassA.stringa = something;` how do I do that?

Briefly, I want to have a list of items that the user can choose from be the content of a dialogue, and have their selection be saved and accessible to the class that called for the creation of the dialogue. Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong but I got tired of dealing with other 'kludges' involving using spinners to do the same thing.

Because `onClick` can't have non-final objects declared elsewhere (at least that is my understanding) I thought maybe I could get around that by calling to another method, `setChoice` that would store the value of whatever was chosen. I would definitively say this is a kludge and would love to be shown the light as to how you are supposed to deal with these things.

Comment: To me, your code has a funny smell and looks to be a possible kludge. Why not use OOP techniques,  create an interface and call the appropriate interface method using the power of polymorphism? Also, why the *static* variable?

Comment: @Hovercraft, the fact that he's actually setting a variable of the caller in the called method, makes it worse than a smell. `stringa=polka;` would have been sufficient instead of `setted.setChoice(this, stringa, polka);`. Somehow he's trying to abstract away an assignment statement.

Comment: @Hovercraft, best name ive seen on here yet. you could be completely right and i hope someone will include that as one of the answers, if not ill have to read up on interfaces. @Vineet, I said it was an extreme simplification. i have updated the bottom of the question with what i am trying to do in general and what i was trying to use this specific code for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not have closures, but you can get close with anonymous inner classes.

```
String output;
public void onCreate() {
    Setter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            output  = "selected";
        }
    });
}
```

See also this swing tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Edit:
In spirit of your example, this should look like this:

```
public class Setter
{
public void setChoice(IsetString setter, String something)
    {
    setter.setString(something);
    }
}


class ClassA extends Activity implements setString
{
static String stringa;
string polka = "dots";
Setter setted = new Setter();
...
public void onCreate()
    {
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    setted.setChoice(new IsetString() {

        @Override
        public void setString(String s) {
            stringa = s;
        }
    }, polka);
    ...
    }
}

interface IsetString {
    void setString(String s);
}
```

Comment: hrm i will look into this more when i get off work, i might have skimmed the chapter on interfaces ...

Comment: i am still not entirely clear what this answer does for me, forgive my ignorance. also, see the edits above, i think its a lot more obvious what i was going for now.

Comment: I do not understand what you try to do at all. Basically it looks like you want to use reflection to do something that shouldn't be done with reflection. Also, your question is so polluted with a half baked attempt to use reflection that i can't even filter out the real question anymore.
You use a `Context` i do not understand since you pass `ClassA extends Activity` into it, you get a array from Context that's not there either. I suppose you want to set a certain value to a certain variable, but i can't figure out where it comes from and where it should go.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer - use [the Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

The long answer - you'll need to obtain access to the [`Fields`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) of the desired Context `Class`. Once you gain access to the Field instances, you can set their values using the [set()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) method; the API call is a bit tricky in that you'll need to pass in the object reference (the context object and not the context class) whose field you wish to modify.

It is necessary that your `Context`, `choice` and `something` parameters to the method, contain the necessary information to make this operation as simple as possible. In other words, the Context class might have to contain the actual `Class` object (or provides a way to get one) that contains the field.

Comment: i took a stab in the dark at using `Field` ... and the results were pretty much what you would expect. see edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection for that. Suppose you context is class itself

```
public void setChoice(Class<?> context, String choice, String something)
{
   try {
     Field f = context.getDeclaredField(choice);
     f.set(null, something);
   } catch (....) {
   }
}
```

Add proper exception handling

---

Note that first argument to `set` is null. That is only valid for static methods. So you may want to check that method is static using `f.getModifiers()`.

Comment: You might want to state why the first arg in the call `f.set(null, something);` is null. For an instance member, that will result in a NullPointerException.

Comment: yours seems to be the simplest solution except when I try to pass a `Class` object, i get this message: "Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized" with the only suggestions being "Infer Generic Type Arguments" or "add suppress warnings" could i get some more help please?

Comment: `Class<?>` should work. In any case, it's just a warning that does not stop compilation. I updated the answer in that respect.

Comment: hrm ok, that seems to be what i tried to do in my question (i updated it to reflect code that i added to try and implement what you suggested) am i getting the class wrong maybe?

Comment: At this point I just don't get what your problem is. If you get some compiler errors/warning be clear about them. Just add compiler output to the question.